# Can anyone help me understand this method used to generate a Huffman tree?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understanding this code, which is about generating a [Huffman tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).  What is the use of this method in this code? Please explain it clearly. Thanks

```
public static Byte toByte(String str) {
    int io = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        io += Math.pow(2, i) * Byte.parseByte(str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1) + "");
    }
    return (byte) io;
}
```

Comment: What about reading the code and trying to figure it out yourself? Since no unusual classes are used and the name is "speaking" it shouldn't be too hard (hint: a string is converted to a byte, with some potential loss of course).

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: i am a beginner your accent is not so good bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking quickly at the code, it would appear that the method is used to convert a String of bits representing a byte to an actual `byte`.  For example, it would translate "1101" to a byte value 0x0D.

It does this by analysing each individual character in the string, starting at the least significant character (ie: `str.charAt(str.length()-1 -i)` ), converting it to a byte (value in theory should be 0 or 1), and then multiplying it by a power of 2 depending on its location in the string (ie: `Math.pow(2,i)`), where the least significant position has a factor of 0.

It sums up all the "bits" and gives you a final answer.

Not - that there seems to be no error checking on the individual bits that it is parsing in the string, but there should only be 0 and 1 represented in the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about generating a [Huffman tree](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html), this tutorial should help you.

As it is, your code example is creating a `Byte` for a given `String`.

Could you give more context as to where this method is being used?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure this out from the method name, parameter type, and return type.
i.e. The method accepts a `String`, returns a `Byte`, and is called `toByte`. One would imagine that the `String`, is changed `toByte` and that the `Byte` is returned.

In so far as how it does this, it iterates across each character of the string and figures out the byte (via `Byte.parseByte`) that represents that character, then appends that to the final `io` byte.

It should be noted that a char in java consists of 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes, and the method attempts to look at strings, so you will not be getting a byte representation of the entire string in most cases.