# Understanding the conversion of Byte to String

Tags: java, logic

I completed a Huffman code which I downloaded from the internet, but i didn't understand the main purpose of the code below. I know it changes byte to string literals but I don't know how. I would be thankful if you would explain the syntax for me.

```
public static String to_String(Byte byt, int len) {
    String tmp = Integer.toBinaryString(byt);
    if (tmp.length() > 8) {
        tmp = tmp.substring(24);
    }
    while (tmp.length() < 8) {
        tmp = "0" + tmp;
    }

    return tmp.substring(8 - len);
}
```

Comment: This is a repost of your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8990350/101095

Comment: The last 4 lines or so are just putting a bunch of "0" at the beginning of the string to pad it out to 8 characters long.

Comment: @Cuga, no, this looks like a method that does the inverse of the one in his previous question.

Comment: If you use a debugger, you can step through the code and see exactly what it's doing, step by step. It's a really good learning tool as well as it's use for figuring out why things aren't working like you think they should.

Comment: -1 Unless others answers, I think my answer should be accepted. You seem not to care much about the others taking time to answer to you.

Answer (score 2):

Shortly

In computers a byte is 8 bits.
In Java a byte is signed so values are between -127 and +127 (and not 0 to 255).

------- Reading the byte into a string -------

```
String tmp = Integer.toBinaryString(byt);
```

This part of your code converts the Byte to String. When it is a positive value everything is "logical". I mean the string represents the byte. i.e. byte value of 10 -> 1010.

------- Handling negative values -------

What happens with negative value ?

The following code handles the negative value.

```
if (tmp.length() > 8) {
    tmp = tmp.substring(24);
}
```

.toBinaryString will give back a 32 bit (char) string in case of negative values
11111111111111111111111111110110
but as you need only a byte (8 bits) so tmp now takes only the last 8 values. .substring(24). It assign the value starting at the 24th unto the end (32th position).

In our case (-10), tmp becomes 11110110

Note : by the way I'm asking myself if on a 64 bits JVM the returned value would be a 64 bits (char) string.

------- Writing a 8 character string -------

The next part of your code simply ensure that the byte is really represented by a string of 8 characters.

```
while (tmp.length() < 8) {
    tmp = "0" + tmp;
}
```

In the case of a value of 10, the string given by .toBinaryString is 1010. But the correct representation is 00001010 so you add leading "0" until you reach a length of 8.

------- returning the string -------

```
return tmp.substring(8 - len);
```

Personally I don't understand this line. This line shorten the result to only give the bits corresponding to "len". Perhpas it has something to do with your specific function.

For me, if the goal issimply to convert a byte to a 8 bit (char) string I would simply have written

```
return tmp;
```

and would have "int len" removed in the header as well

```
public static String to_String(Byte byt)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is an excellent and very descriptive answer to a very vague question.